# VSCode Regular Expression - appears not to work

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

If I try to use a regular expression in Find (F3) it appear not to work:

[T]opic highlights both 'Topic' & 'topic' in my code.

Is my syntax wrong or does VSCode not really do regular expressions (this may be a whole 'visual studio' thing).

Thanks for looking.

Comment: By the way, the regex: `[T]opic` is literally the same thing as just writing `Topic`...

Answer (score 0):

Just enable a **case sensitive** search:

[image]

Actually, a character class is not necessary here, you can search for just `Topic`. A character class is handy when you need to match a single character from a known set, and here, it does not look to be the case.